# Criptografia AES256 com JCE

Tags: criptografia, app, aes

Estou usando criptografia AES256 em um projeto de comunicação e gostaria de saber se existe alguma restrição no uso dessa criptografia com a JCE (Java Cryptography Extension Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy), e qual a implicação do uso dessa JCE no desenvolvimento de APPs comerciais.

Comment: Quando você diz "restrição no uso" e "implicação do uso" você fala em termos técnicos, jurídicos, de regulamentação, ...? Não entendi exatamente o que você quer saber. O AES-256 é um bom algoritmo, mas sozinho ele não serve pra nada (é preciso um modo de operação/ *padding*, e a menos que ambos os participantes já conheçam a chave simétrica, também é preciso um método de negociação de chaves). Normalmente ele é usado como parte de uma ***suite* criptográfica**, e protocolos padronizados costumam dar suporte a um conjunto bem específico de *suites*.

Comment: No caso, a restrição refere-se ao aspecto jurídico, em relação aos termos de uso impostos aos desenvolvedores na instalação desse módulo. Parece que há uma restrição de uso desse módulo em alguns países, que não inclui o Brasil. Minha dúvida é se essa restrição é válida para aplicativos desenvolvidos no Brasil, e que são instalados por usuários residentes em países incluídos nessa restrição.

Comment: Nesse caso, receio que essa pergunta esteja fora do escopo do SOpt. Ainda que seja de interesse, seria difícil encontrar pessoas que tivessem (e pudessem comprovar) expertise nesses aspectos jurídicos relevantes. Em especial se tratando da lei de dois países distintos (a criptografia em geral está sujeita a restrições de exportação pelos EUA, sendo classificada como "munição"; não sei que tratamento recebe do Brasil, nem como fica isso na lei internacional).